# Php validate with preg_match

Tags: php

I try to validate fields. Three fields that may only contain numbers. The fields have the variable names $num1, $num2, $num3. I have put them in an array and then I run preg_match but it does not work. How should I do?

```
$valnum = array (‘$num1’, ‘$num2’, ‘$num3’);
    if (preg_match('/[0-9]/', $valnum)){
echo $mycost;
}
    else {
echo 'You can only enter numbers';  
    }
```

Comment: `[0-9]` will only match a single digit. Also, `preg_match` takes a string as its second parameter, not an array.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Actually [0-9]  will match any string with a number in it.

Comment: Are you using a word processing tool such as MS word to write your code? You have typographical quotes in your code which will not work. You should really consider using a text editor such as `Notepad++` or `GVim`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   is_numeric()
```

would be a better approach

//worked up example:

```
<?php
$num1 = '1';
$num2 = '11';
$num3 = '11.11';

$mycost = '$99.99';

$valnum = array($num1,$num2,$num3);
$check = '';
foreach($valnum as $element){
    if(!is_numeric($element)){
        $check = 'bad';
        break;
    }
}

if($check=='bad'){
    echo 'You can only enter numbers';
}else{
    echo $mycost;
}
```

?>

returns 99.99

Comment: $valnum = array (‘$num1’, ‘$num2’, ‘$num3’);

 foreach ($valnum as $element) {
    if (is_numeric($element)) {
        echo $mycost;
    } else {
       echo 'You can only enter numbers'; 
    }
}

Comment: I get the error message "You can only enter numbers" when I enter something in the fields, even numbers.

Comment: I don't see how, sure they are all numbers? see worked up version above

Comment: Sorry, I wrote $valnum = array('$num1','$num2','$num3'); but It works fine when I write $valnum = array($num1,$num2,$num3);

Comment: I just wonder, shouldn't It work with'' around my variables in the array as well?

Comment: Sorry but I have one more question. The error message only displays when all variables in the array are something else than numbers. I want to show the error message even if only one or two of the varibles aren't numbers. How can I do that with this type of solution?

Comment: you can remove the break, and or swap if\else order. just try it wand work through it logically.

Comment: I have removed the break; but now I get three messages, one for each variable. I only want one message and I only want mycost to be shown if all three variables are numbers.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at that. I hope that you answer for free here on this kind of beginner questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `filter_var` as it is desgined for this type of validation:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 'a', 'b');
var_dump(filter_var_array($array, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
```

Output:

```
array
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => boolean false
  3 => boolean false
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php

Comment: "numbers" may not = integers.

Comment: I use is_numeric () now but I'll try this solution too when I get time. Thank you.

Comment: @Dagon http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.constants.php will show you available filter types. Number being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you demand checking numeric input by `preg_match()` you should:

- at first add `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) [meta characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) to your regexp
- add handling for floats
- consider removing spaces from string (user may decide to input `1 800` instead of `1800`)
- use `\d` - [escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) for decimal numbers group

So final regexp would look like: `~^\d+([.,]\d+)?$~`.

You should rather use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/is_numeric) but according to manual it accepts "science format":

> Finds whether the given variable is numeric. Numeric strings consist
>   of optional sign, any number of digits, optional decimal part and
>   optional exponential part. Thus +0123.45e6 is a valid numeric value.
>   Hexadecimal notation (0xFF) is allowed too but only without sign,
>   decimal and exponential part.

Which I personally avoid, this function just allows to input too much and you have to worry about transformation to valid form.

There'are two nice functions [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and [`floatval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) with just a little example:

```php
$numbers = array( '1.8', '3', 'hello');

foreach( $numbers as $i){
    var_dump( $i);
    var_dump( intval( $i));
    var_dump( floatval( $i));
    echo "\n";
}
```

And output:

```
string(3) "1.8"
int(1)
float(1.8)

string(1) "3"
int(3)
float(3)

string(5) "hello"
int(0)
float(0)
```

Which allows you to do this:

```
php > $str = "3.8";
php > $i = intval( $str);
php > var_dump( $i == $str);
bool(false)
php > $str = "3";
php > $i = intval( $str);
php > var_dump( $i == $str);
bool(true)
```

You also can use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php), but those functions just doesn't work for me and I'd build function like this:

```
function get_integer( $input){
    if( $input === null){
         return null;
    }

    if( $input === ''){
         return null;
    }

    $i = intval( $input);
    if( $i != $input){
         return null;
    }

    return $i;
}

$myCol = get_integer( $_POST['foo']);
if( $myCol === null){
    die( 'You naughty boy!');
}
```